# How to validate a div according to cookie set in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am setting cookie in Jquery according to screen width . Like this

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit','#outerPage',function(){

   var windowWidth = $(this).width();
  // alert(windowWidth);
   if(windowWidth <290)
   {    
       console.log('cookie:small');
       $.cookie("adds", 0);
       //setTestCookie("adds","0");
   }
   else
   {   
    console.log('cookie :Big');
       $.cookie("adds", 1);
      //0setTestCookie("adds","1");
   }
});
</script>
```

And then I am using these cookie to validate a div in php along with some other parameter in the same file like this

```
<?php
    if($current_item == 2 && $_COOKIE['adds'] == '1')
    {
    //place the adsense after the third ad.
    ?>
    <div id="bloque" class="addsTpl addBigphone" style="min-height:90px">
    <div class="google_add">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- resultmobile -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-765756"
         data-ad-slot="657567"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script></div>
    </div     
    <?php
    }
?>
```

So far so good .The problem I am facing is that the if() statement is only getting true after I reload the page .

What I have understood is that the cookie is set after the server if() statement is executed in the first time as the Jquery will execute only after the server script is done loading .

Can any one suggest me any other method I can use to do this .

Thanks & regards

Comment: php runs on the server-side, so of course it will be visible after page reload, try to implement your logic on the client-side

Answer (score 2):

thats correct, the server side code is running first and serving up you page which only then executes the javascript - which is too late for you

You could move the window size test that you run to set the cookie into an earlier page  in your app (e.g. a login page) or you could have a 'hidden' page which runs your javascript and then immediately redirects to your main page e.g.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit','#outerPage',function(){

   var windowWidth = $(this).width();
  // alert(windowWidth);
   if(windowWidth <290)
   {    
       console.log('cookie:small');
       $.cookie("adds", 0);
       //setTestCookie("adds","0");
   }
   else
   {   
    console.log('cookie :Big');
       $.cookie("adds", 1);
      //0setTestCookie("adds","1");
   }
   // redirect to the actual page you want
   document.location.href = 'new main page url'
});
</script>
```

So your hidden page is never rendered  - it just runs the javascript and then redirects to the main page.

Hope that helps
    Garrett

Comment: Yeah right for time being I am executing the code on my indexpage  :P . Its doing the trick but . Suppose we sent a url to user in an email and that contains the page that I have the google add. So in that case my code is not running . Maybe I will try  to use the other option you mentioned :) .

Comment: The other thing you could look at is to inject the entire div and its contents into the DOM using javascript (as Teo hinted), doing everything in client-side. In fac tyou may be able to have the entire div already on your page with 'display: none' style and only run the '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});' javascript if the window is big enough

Comment: Yes this could be a possibility but if I keep two adds in a page then google will block my  add-sense account as its against the google policy to keep more than one adds on the same page. Although the adds are not visible but in the DOm they will exist and when . The google bot find that then it will block the account